# In Bridge, Is There A Way To Shorten "Reaction Time" For "Real Time" Play

Tags: bridge

I like to solve bridge problems in newspapers. When I do this, I often get the correct answer, or at least come "within sight" (e.g. get the key idea but "muff" the sequence). This process typically takes 2-3 minutes, because I start by inventorying outstanding trumps and honors, plan the play suit by suit, and identify potential problems.

It's different, in "real time play." Here, when dummy hits the table, I get 15, at most 30 seconds to study it before beginning (e.g declarer) play. If I take longer, others at the table start to grumble.

So I end up playing "by instinct"; I need to clear suit X, or I need to draw trumps or no, I need to save trumps for "transportation." This works "quite well," (relative to my peer group). But I fear that I'm blowing hands, or at least relying on opponents' mistakes, when I actually have a "forced" win.

I do have two advantages in "real time" that I don't have with newspaper columns. 1) I see my hand beforehand. 2) I've heard the bidding beforehand. Whereas, with a newspaper column, I see dummy, my hand, and the bidding simultaneously.

If I were in a tournament, would I get a "reasonable" amount of time (say 1 minute) to study the board before I play?

Or does anyone know of a way that I can speed up my "newspaper" reaction time to that of the much faster "real time" play?

Comment: Sounds to me like you're playing with the wrong people. I don't think there should be a rush to figure out how to play a hand.

Comment: @dave: I take your point--up to a point. Even allowing for this fact, my guess it that it takes me more time than is "convntionally" acceptable (e.g. in tournaments). So I want to find out 1) how long is "conventionally" acceptable, and 2) how to get to this point.

Comment: I think this would be very applicable with respect to tournament play: it's still OK for casual play, but I think time should be much less of a factor in casual play.

Comment: also of course newspaper columns don't tend to print boring hands, in real play some hands are obvious how to play as soon as revealed

Comment: The other day I played a "speedball" tournament in which we had 4 minutes per game. That worked!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In tournaments, there is no time limit, official or unofficial *for a hand or trick*; taking 5 minutes to play to the first trick is not unusual.  Tournaments don't grind to a halt (i) because there *is* usually a time limit for a section or session (so you play most hands quickly and have time to spare on the tricky ones) and (ii) because by the time somebody has reached tournament level, he or she will have enough experience to recognize the simple situations (draw trumps/crossruff, duck a trick/cash winners), and will only take a long time for genuinely complex decisions.  The *only* way to reach this point, I am sorry to say, is practice. Find a group who take the game seriously enough to take time over it: join a duplicate club: make a mental note after every hand of the one thing you want to remember about it.  And then get some more practice.  It won't on its own make you a good player (ask any of my partners), but it will improve your speed.

(There is also the factor that tournament players have to write down their system of bidding and discards, so don't have to worry about remembering them; but it sounds like you shouldn't worry about that at present.)

Comment: Welcome to the site. Thanks for the answer (a good one). An upvote AND an acceptance.

Comment: -1: The statement that there are no time limits in tournaments is blatantly wrong. There are _official_ limits in most major tournaments (depends on the locale/tournament, though), and teams/pairs can be penalized for slow play. The limits usually aren't per trick though, and are over a certain set of hands etc.

Comment: @Aryabhata; maybe I read the question wrong, but I thought OP was asking about a time limit for a hand, which hasn't applied in any tournament I've ever seen.  Continuing slow play is a different matter, I agree.

Comment: @Tim: In essence, there is an 'average' limit per hand. So if you play one very slow, but blitz through the others, it is usually ok. The -1 was for saying there are no time limits whatsoever.

Comment: Oddly enougn, I have more leeway in a tournament than I do with my (rather contentious) tablemates. Apparently, if I take 2-3 minutes to study a difficult hand, then play "quickly" after that (because of what I've learned) I'm ok. – Tom Au 0 secs ago edit

Comment: @aryabhata: Tim, will you edit your answer to conform to our new understanding? Aryabhata, would you remove your downvote if Tim edits his answer to your satisfaction.?

Comment: @Tom. OK by me.  But I didn't take offence at the downvote, and don't usually feel my answers have to be edited into perfection :)  And yes, serious players know some hands are tricky; purely social ones often don't care.

Comment: @tim: The goal of the site is to improve the quality of questions and answers. That's the purpose of downvotes. These can be removed after edits that improve the "quality."

Comment: "There is also the factor that tournament players have to write down their system of bidding and discards, so don't have to worry about remembering them" Eh? No, this is done because the rules of duplicate bridge require that your opponents know certain things about your conventions.

Answer (score 2):

By all means take 1 minute to study the hand.  Often this minor delay actually speeds up the play later in the hand and allows an early claim.  If you count your hand review the bidding add up points and imagine a detailed "target distribution" for the opponent's hand you know the most about the last five tricks of the hand will go in a flash. Instead of grumbling about your slow play you can grumble back at them when they cant decide what to discard on the last few tricks. (No not really but sometimes i would like to.)

Comment: Welcome to the site. Thanks your answer. An upvote to get you started.